# variable without quotes, different response live and local

Tags: php, php-5.6, incompatibility

I am currently checking the deprecated functions of a software developed in older PHP. It was developed in 2006. And I've seen a lot of variables in this format **`$_SESSION[name]`** or **`$_GET[name]`**.

The issue here is that it does not give error on the deployed site. But in my local it gives **`Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`**.

I know that I can solve this by adding single or double quotes on each variable but there are a lot to edit. And I have no access to the server configurations.

Any idea why this does not work on my local. I use PHP 5.6.

**EDIT:: I just want to know the reason behind.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of odd Scenario, you have a hint from the E-Notice: `Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`. Since you don't have access to the server, (and until you do) You may simply create a temporal File say: `_DEFINES.php` and include it in your Scripts. Inside that File, you may just define those variables as Strings like so:

```
<?php 
    defined('name')           or define('name',           'name');
    defined('another_string') or define('another_string', 'another_value');
    defined('yet_another')    or define('yet_another',    'yet_another');
```

That way, you may have temporarily beat the nightmare...

**NOTE:** *This is not much of a Solution... it is just a temporal* ***work-around*** *till you can fix the issue from the server-side....*

Comment: Thanks I can do that but what I need to know is the reason why it works.. I am using the copy of the live software. But it 'renders' differently.

Comment: @makoto    The reason it works is already in the `E-Notice`. It is because it expects `name` to be a `String` but found something that appeared to be a `Constant`. Then since it cannot find that constant anywhere, PHP Engine automatically tries to help out by assuming/converting that `FALSE CONSTANT` to a `LITERAL STRING EQUIVALENT` and then tries to warn/inform you to `NOTICE` what it has done: **converted what seemed to be an undeclared Constant to a simple String.** That's it...